# Frame does not exist when run Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu 18.04, ros melodic to simulate my URDF robot in gazebo. Then I create a dynamic node to move the robot. When I publish gazebo_msgs/ModelState with reference_frame set as "world_ned" in the dynamic node I created before, I was getting an error : "Updating ModelState: for model[MyrobotName], specified reference frame entity [world_ned] does not exist " , even though I already used a  static_transform_publisher in my launch file. But when I simulate it in my rviz, there is no error like I said before. This is my tf tree :
[image: image description]
and this is my launch file :

```
<launch>
<!-- Configurable arguments -->
<arg name="enable_rviz" default="true"/>
<arg name="robot_name" default="MyrobotName"/>    
<node name="world2ned" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="0 0 0 0 0 3.1415 world world_ned 100"/>

<!-- Robot description -->
<arg name="model" default="$(find gb_description)/urdf/myrobotname.urdf"/>
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(arg model)" />

<arg name="x_pos" default="0.0"/>
<arg name="y_pos" default="0.0"/>
<arg name="z_pos" default="0.5"/>

<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
<arg name="paused" value="false"/>
<arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
<arg name="gui" value="true"/>
<arg name="headless" value="false"/>
<arg name="debug" value="false"/>
</include>

<!-- Load configs in their node namespace -->
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find gb_sim)/config/dynamics.yaml"/>


<!-- Start nodes -->
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" output="screen"/>
<node name="dynamics_node" pkg="gb_sim" type="dynamics_node.py" output="screen"/>


<!-- RViz -->
<node if="$(arg enable_rviz)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find gb_description)/scene/test1.rviz"/>

<node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_urdf"  args="-urdf -model MyrobotName -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />
</launch>
```

Does anyone know how to solve it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379323/frame-does-not-exist-when-run-gazebo/) by [jenanaputra](https://answers.ros.org/users/58305/jenanaputra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-05-31**:
Could you provide more details? Maybe an image of your tf tree?

**Comment by [jenanaputra](https://answers.ros.org/users/58305/jenanaputra/) on 2021-05-31**:
Sure, I have already provided the image of my tf tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> with reference_frame set as
> "my_new_frame" in the node I created
> before

So as you can see from your tf tree above, there is no frame called `my_new_frame`.

> I already used a
> static_transform_publisher in my
> launch file

If you are using a static_transform_publisher to generate this frame, there is something wrong going on there because you must be able to see the frame. **Can you show us how you are calling your static transform publisher?**

> But when I simulate it in my rviz,
> there is no error

Unfortunately RViz is not a simulator. It is only a visualizer that lets you view your robot model (in this case). You can add the /tf topic in rviz to view the tree as well. It is likely that your `my_new_frame` wont show up there too.

EDIT (after launch file):
Your launch file does not have a static_transform_publisher that generates "my_new_frame". What is your "my_new_frame" supposed to link to? You will have to add a second static_transform_publisher from that link to "my_new_frame" for this to work.

---

Originally posted by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) with karma: 459 on 2021-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-06-01**:
Can you share your launch file too?

**Comment by [jenanaputra](https://answers.ros.org/users/58305/jenanaputra/) on 2021-06-01**:
Sure , I've already update my question above, so you can give  me an advice about that. I just realized that when I removed a line `<include file="$(find gazebo_ros) ......`     and removed a line `<node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" ......`    on my launch file, there is no  error like I said before.

**Comment by [jenanaputra](https://answers.ros.org/users/58305/jenanaputra/) on 2021-06-01**:
I set my_new_frame to world_ned

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-06-02**:
Then you will need to add something like this:
`<node name="newframe2world" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 my_new_frame world_ned 100"/>`